# How do I check for empty values within the controller parameters? (Ruby on Rails 5) - FIXED

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

I would appreciate any ideas because I've searched the documentation and this site and can't seem to find anything that helps.

I'm building a small business management application, that will deal with sales and stock. One of the functionalities is updating a sale (if the user wants to add an item they missed or selected the wrong product and wants to correct that, for example).

In order for the products' stock to be correct, I'm trying to restore the stock substracted when the sale was recorded to its previous state before saving the update (i.e. before the parameters change, otherwise the stock would be substracted twice). To do that, I'm trying to devise a way to check if the update will go through in case somehow the form lets through some empty params (e.g. empty "Product" field), to avoid errors.

I  want to grab all the parameters, transaction and nested individual items , and check if any of them are empty/nil.

This is a snippet from the controller where the action happens:

```
    @inflow.restore_stock
    respond_to do |format|
      if @inflow.update(inflow_params)
        @inflow.substract_stock
```

The actual methods that do the thing:

```
def restore_stock
    self.update_stocks(false)
end

def substract_stock
    self.update_stocks(true)
end

def update_stocks(substract)
    self.items.each do |item|
        if substract
            value = -item.quantity
        else
            value = item.quantity
        end
        item.product.update_stock(value)
    end
end
```

For readability and DRYness, the boolean happens here instead of the controller.

Also, the methods `update_stock` and  `update_stocks` are in their respective models, again for DRYness. They take that value and update the corresponding attribute.

I've tried `.empty?`, but if any are not, it goes through anyway. What I'm looking for is if any of them are.

Other problem I've had is that empty methods look only for nil, and sometimes it's just blank, and it goes through.

The closest things I've found are two ActionController:Parameters methods, `has_value?(value)` and `value?(value)`, but they need to be fed a specific value, and I don't have that information. I need to cycle through the parameters and find if any of them are empty/nil, so the restore won't go through.

Any ideas? Any info needed will be promptly provided.

Thanks a bunch!

### Update:

Validations for presence are already in the model and the requirements are in the controller. I wanted to make sure no corner case could seriously mess up the stock values.

After trying out the suggestions (`.blank?` and `.present?`), I came across ActiveRecord::Transactions, and it turned out to be exactly what I needed: if the update doesn't succeed, everything rolls back. And it's also great because it doesn't require lengthy methods.

Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: have you tried using the method `blank?`. `nil.blank?`, `{}.blank?`, `[].blank?`, `"".blank?`, all of them return `true`

Comment: you can try `.present?` if it exists it will go through.

Comment: Please read "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)" and "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"

Comment: check if require method solves your problem.
[https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Parameters/require]

Comment: Also I think model validation is what you should use.  This will prevent any wrong values to be put into records

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks! Gave them a read, found them super interesting. Any particular reason why you linked them? i.e. could you maybe point out what bothered you about my post? So I can improve. Thanks again.

Comment: See the [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59725574/revisions) to the text. Concise and to the point is important. Don't waste time with fluff, as it wastes our time when trying to get to the point to try to help you. "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)"
is a great read and is recommended often.